# При свертывании экрана анимация не работает

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

У меня 3 слоя движутся с разной скоростью в setInterval, если хоть слегка свернуть браузер, то движется только нижний шарик. Из-за чего такое может быть? http://5ee03865.ngrok.com/

**Обновление**

Разрешение 1920 на 1080.

chrome, mozila, в IE вообще не работает, ни в 9, ни в 10.

Когда высота меньше 980 и больше примерно 700, то .load-top console.log(layout.css(property)); //429 все время прибавление не идет, если окно браузера другая, все работает норм.

Comment: браузер какой?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Андрей Перов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если в некоторых browser не работает, то нужно добавить к анимации

---

```
-webkit-animation:

 -o-animation:

-moz-animation:

animation:
```

---

и проверить keyframes

```
 /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {

      //some code
}
```

---